# Is H.P Lovecraft sci-fi/fantasy?

Tags: discussion

Many people know H.P. Lovecraft for his Cthulhu mythos and generally assume anything with tentacles is of his work. He is widely known as a horror-fiction author, which is entirely true, but he does much more than that

Much of his work, at the time, dealt with what was considered science fiction. He tackles such things as alchemy, space travel, magic, mythological beings, fictional medical practices, great fictional kingdoms, and even alien beings.

Personally, I would consider Lovecraft sci-fi before sci-fi was really a thing (his work dates around 1910-1920), but I can understand that many people misunderstand Lovecraft, and to my knowledge there is no horror SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[h-p-lovecraft](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h-p-lovecraft)

Sure seems like it to me.

Comment: I swear I miss every tag

Comment: I think the only real debate is whether it's science fiction or fantasy. But that's more of a chat subject than a meta subject.

Comment: @Donald.McLean maybe if you're looking at a specific story. He does both

Comment: Just because a tag exists, doesn't necessarily mean it is a good way of determining whether something is sci fi or fantasy. As an example, I once started a tag for "homosexuality," which I still think I'm the only person to ever use, as I was interested in a few sci fi and fantasy novels where major characters were homosexual. I started the tag as an easy way of finding those questions again in the future. That hardly means that "homosexuality" is sci fi or fantasy!  With that stated, I am in full agreement that H.P. Lovecraft qualifies.

Comment: @JamesSheridan The author tag was a quick and easy way to answer the question.  Author tags are way different from topic/theme tags, since they clearly answer 'is this author's stuff on topic at all?' questions.  All topic/theme tags obviously are only on topic in relation to works of sci-fi and fantasy that make use of them.

Comment: @Keen: I wasn't arguing.